# Does Discarding Class Instance removes MouseListener

Tags: java, mouselistener

I have a `class` which `implements` `MouseListner`.
If i set this `class` instance to `null` will it remove `MouseListener` from the JPanel? or Do i have to manually remove `MouseListening` from `JPanel` using `removeMouseListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only set your reference to the `MouseListener` to null. That means that you can't access the `MouseListener` through that variable, but the `MouseListener` itself still exists, so you must remove it from the `JPanel` using `removeMouseListener`.

Comment: why? If class instance implementing listener is null then how can MouseListener live?

Comment: Class instance isn't null. Your reference to it (your variable) is null.

Comment: The class instance implementing the mouse listener didn't go anywhere, it didn't "become null". It is still in memory, and it still listens to mouse events. All you did was set the reference to it to null. The reference is like the address of a house. If you remove the address from a postcard, the house doesn't disappear.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the mouse listener.